# Why do I get TypeError when running my Django project with Debug off?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

So I've been running my Django project with Debug on, I know it's wrong, and now trying to make the change. But then, the project returned TypeError when I turned the Debug off: **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType** 
I tried digging into the issue a little more, and found out that the variable `absolute_path` of `admin/js/jquery.js` was `None`, as you can see in the Traceback below. 
I've got three clues regarding this issue:

1. It happens in the `django-cloudinary-storage` library.
2. It probably happened after running `python manage.py collectstatic`. I did not run this command up until now..
3. The project ran perfectly with `Debug = True`. It only happened with `Debug=False`.

    What do you think is the problem? Below is a part of my settings.py and full Traceback.

   settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 31, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 78, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    import_module(module_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crystalize/crystalize/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 61, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.add_files(self.static_root, prefix=self.static_prefix)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 113, in add_files
    self.update_files_dictionary(root, prefix)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 125, in update_files_dictionary
    self.add_file_to_dictionary(url, path, stat_cache=stat_cache)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 136, in add_file_to_dictionary
    static_file = self.get_static_file(path, url, stat_cache=stat_cache)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 210, in get_static_file
    self.add_cache_headers(headers, path, url)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 231, in add_cache_headers
    if self.immutable_file_test(path, url):
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 146, in immutable_file_test
    static_url = self.get_static_url(name_without_hash)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 169, in get_static_url
    return decode_if_byte_string(staticfiles_storage.url(name))
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 166, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 145, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 394, in stored_name
    self.hashed_name(name, content=None, filename=intermediate_name)
  File "/Users/ryanoh/Projects/crysenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cloudinary_storage/storage.py", line 286, in hashed_name
    content = open(absolute_path, 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: According to their documents:

```Please note that you must set DEBUG to False to fetch static files from Cloudinary. With DEBUG equal to True, Django staticfiles app will use your local files for easier and faster development```


I suggest to re-check your staticfiles and cloudinary config according to: https://github.com/klis87/django-cloudinary-storage#usage-with-static-files

Comment: + additional info I found out: I ran `python manage.py findstatic admin/js/jquery.js`, and it couldn't find any. If it helps figuring out the problem.

Comment: @svfat I think that's where the problem began. With setting Debug=False, Django must have tried fetching static files from Cloudinary and somehow got in trouble.. I'm in so much confusion :(